# Loop Query in Access

Tags: sql, loops, ms-access

I have two tables in Acces. The one shows all my accounts called ACCOUNTS (there are duplicates) and the second table shows all the transactions and is called TRANSACTIONS.

**ACCOUNTS**

[image]

**TRANSACTIONS**

[image]

I basically want to create a table showing all the unique account numbers and then the sum of all the debit transactions transaction for each account in one column and then the sum of all the credit transactions for each account in a second columns. Individually the queries will be something as follows:

SELECT DISTINCT(Account_Number) FROM ACCOUNTS

and then

SELECT SUM(Amount) from TRANSACTIONS GROUP BY Debit_Account INTO DEBIT and then SELECT SUM(Amount) from TRANSACTIONS GROUP BY Credit_Account INTO CREDIT

So ultimately you will have a table with the following headings

ACCOUNT
DEBIT
CREDIT

How would I combine the two queries. I am guessing it will be done via a FOR LOOP but not sure how to construct it in Access.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want `left join` and `group by`:

```
select a.account_number, sum(t.amount)
from accounts as a left join
     transactions as t
     on a.account_number = t.account
group by a.account_number;
```

If all the accounts have at least one transaction, then your second query is pretty much what you want:

```
SELECT Account, SUM(Amount) 
FROM TRANSACTIONS
GROUP BY Account;
```

In my opinion, you should always include the `GROUP BY` keys in the `SELECT` of an aggregation query -- unless you have a really good reason for excluding them.

EDIT:

For your revised question, how about just using correlated subqueries:

```
select a.*,
       (select sum(t.amount)
        from transaction as t
        where t.debit_account = a.account_number
       ) as debits,
       (select sum(t.amount)
        from transaction as t
        where t.credit_account = a.account_number
       ) as credits
from account as a
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  I now realize that in my attempt to simplify my question I made it too simple and actually asked a really silly question. I have updated my question to reflect the issue at hand

Comment: Thank you, I think this approach might work. Why am I using the * ?
Should I not be using distinct in order to remove duplicate account codes in TABLE A?

Comment: @gdekoker . . . It doesn't make sense to me that you would have duplicate accounts in a table called `Accounts` -- that seems like it should be the master list.  But given that you do, use `distinct`.  I would be inclined to do that in a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

This code answers the original question.
Join the 2 queries like this

```
SELECT a.Account_Number, a.Account_Name, t.Total
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Account_Number, Account_Name FROM ACCOUNTS) AS a
INNER JOIN (SELECT Account, SUM(Amount) AS Total from TRANSACTIONS GROUP BY Account) AS t
ON t.Account = a.Account_Number
```

If you don't use the 1st query and instead you join the table `ACCOUNTS` then you will get wrong results because the sums will be multiplied by the number of duplicates in the table `ACCOUNTS`.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  I now realize that in my attempt to simplify my question I made it too simple and actually asked a really silly question. I have updated my question to reflect the issue at hand

Comment: This is a totally new requirement that invalidates the answers you already got.